# Does Google also show rich snippets for small sites?

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets

So far, I’ve seen rich snippets in Google search results only for large sites with a high number of elements (people, events, recipes, etc.).

Does anyone know of an example where rich snippets are displayed for a small site with only a handful/a few dozen elements?

Our own site has around 10 events (we are a specialized conference organizer) with rich snippet markup but so far they aren’t displayed. To avoid misunderstandings: I’m interested in hearing about all types, not just events.

To clarify: We are using Google’s rich snippet testing tool. Everything fine there.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I have a feeling it is about as elusive as [getting Google Sitelinks](http://www.seopedia.org/internet-marketing-and-seo/google-sitelinks-the-ultimate-faq/). My recommendation is to follow the [Google guide for Rich Snippits](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170) and when the site gets enough PageRank and keywords hits, it will naturally start appearing.

Also be sure to watch your [webmaster tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) closely and address any issues Google finds. There is also a section called "Sidewiki" under the labs option to force the description text for the main site search result.

[This page](http://knol.google.com/k/google-rich-snippets-tips-and-tricks#) also has useful information and indicates your root cause why they might not be working:

```
Who is eligible for Rich Snippets?
Currently, review sites and social networking/people profile sites are eligible. 
We plan to expand Rich Snippets to other types of content in the future.
```

Comment: Google is working strongly on expanding the number of sites that show rich snippets in the search results. Like Talvi says, make sure that your markup is correct (and try the testing tool at http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets to make double-check) and be patient in the meantime :-).

Comment: Getting sitelinks isn't hard. I've gotten sitelinks on several sites (PR3 or maybe lower) but no rich snippets on a popular site with PR5.

Comment: @John Mueller: Understood, but I was asking for indications on where Google is in this process. I simply haven't seen them for sites that - like ours - have only relatively few elements marked up and I started wondering if we are so far away from this point that our efforts don't make sense at this point in time.

Comment: Sorry but the Sidewiki option in Webmaster Tools has nothing to do with what's shown in the search results. It pertains to the Sidewike functionality of the Google search bar.

Answer (score -1):

With only a few rich snippets, your discoverability is probably low, so you probably want to submit it to google directly:

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/request.py?contact_type=rich_snippets_feedback